# Ubuntu boots but gives no screen

Tags: boot, grub2, screen, plymouth

I got Ubuntu 11.10, with gnome-shell as desktop manager, and whenever I boot(select ubuntu from grub, just so you know where we are) it gives no screen, and if I wait a minute orso, and press the powerbutton, it will activate my screen and turn off(normal way).
Now I found when I just turn it off in mid boot, then when I select ubuntu from grub(not the recovery one) it wil lcheck for errors, it will find no errors but my screen is turned on. I have no clue why my laptop does this.

tl;dr screen will only be turned on when there is a error check involved in the boot.

Anyone?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this in you terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Look for:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it too :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

And update Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And see if it helps if not post wath happens.